# Firebase + REST + jquery produces strange keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, firebase

I am trying to use Firebase to store some data, but I don't want to use their .js library, I want to use jQuery and REST operations.

When I try to translate the successful curl:

```
curl -X PUT -d '{
 "alanisawesome": {
   "name": "Alan Turing",
   "birthday": "June 23, 1912"
 }
}' 'https://blazing-heat-5028.firebaseio.com/users.json'
```

into a $.ajax():

```
  var url = "https://blazing-heat-5028.firebaseio.com/users.json";
  var data = {
   "JQUERY": {
    "name": "Alan Turing",
    "birthday": "June 23, 1912"
  }
 };
 $.ajax({
   accept: "application/json",
   method: 'POST',
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",
   data: JSON.stringify(data),
   url: url
 })
 .done((data)=> {
   document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data)
 })
```

it produces strange alphanumeric keys in the database.

[image: Strange keys in the database]

Here is a jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ecb70js8/1/

Any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those "strange alphanumeric keys" are Firebase push ids. When you `POST` to a location, the server creates a new item at that location and generates the key for it. In Firebase's case, those keys are push ids.

From the [Firebase documentation for the REST API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/saving-data.html#section-post):

> To generate a unique, timestamp-based key for every child added to a Firebase database reference we can send a POST request.
>
> ...
>
> Notice that the key `-JSOpn9ZC54A4P4RoqVa` was automatically generated for us because we used a POST request.

If you don't like the auto-generated keys, you can also generate your own key and then `PUT` to that specific location.